# How to visualise a simple std::string with natvis?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015, natvis

I can't have a decent view of a basic std:string in VS2015 while debugging.
I followed the instructions given at this address :https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/jj620914.aspx
(that is debugger type set to native mode, and uncheck both `Use Managed Compatibility Mode` and  `Use Native Compatibility Mode`) . I have also added the stl.nativs file to my solution.

Currently my debugger looks like : 
[image]

I would like to see as a value directly "test" for my variable `str` (instead of a very complex tree). Can you help me with this ?

Comment: What kind of Natvis XML file did you include for your test case ?

Comment: thanks - see my answer - the stl.natvis file was not considered by the debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the answer, for a very strange reason the stl.natvis file that I found in my VS Installation directory ( `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers` for me ) and that I have added to my project **is not** recognised by the debugger automatically.

So the solution was to add another `Debugger visualization file (.natvis)` to my solution (right click ->add new item ) and to copy/past the content of the  `stl.natvis` file to this new file. After rebuild, the standard std:string is appropriately displayed by the debugger.

For completeness, see below the part of the `stl.natvis` that deals with std::string for visual studio 2015.

```
<!-- VC 2015 -->
  <Type Name="std::basic_string&lt;char,*&gt;">
    <DisplayString Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &lt; _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">{_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf,na}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &gt;= _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">{_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr,na}</DisplayString>
    <StringView Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &lt; _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf,na</StringView>
    <StringView Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &gt;= _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr,na</StringView>
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="[size]" ExcludeView="simple">_Mypair._Myval2._Mysize</Item>
      <Item Name="[capacity]" ExcludeView="simple">_Mypair._Myval2._Myres</Item>
      <Item Name="[allocator]" ExcludeView="simple">_Mypair</Item>
      <ArrayItems>
        <Size>_Mypair._Myval2._Mysize</Size>
        <ValuePointer Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &lt; _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf</ValuePointer>
        <ValuePointer Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &gt;= _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr</ValuePointer>
      </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
  </Type>

  <!-- VC 2015 -->
  <Type Name="std::basic_string&lt;wchar_t,*&gt;">
    <AlternativeType Name="std::basic_string&lt;unsigned short,*&gt;" />
    <AlternativeType Name="std::basic_string&lt;char16_t,*&gt;" />
    <DisplayString Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &lt; _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">{_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf,su}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &gt;= _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">{_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr,su}</DisplayString>
    <StringView Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &lt; _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf,su</StringView>
    <StringView Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &gt;= _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr,su</StringView>
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="[size]" ExcludeView="simple">_Mypair._Myval2._Mysize</Item>
      <Item Name="[capacity]" ExcludeView="simple">_Mypair._Myval2._Myres</Item>
      <Item Name="[allocator]" ExcludeView="simple">_Mypair</Item>
      <ArrayItems>
        <Size>_Mypair._Myval2._Mysize</Size>
        <ValuePointer Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &lt; _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf</ValuePointer>
        <ValuePointer Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &gt;= _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr</ValuePointer>
      </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
  </Type>

  <Type Name="std::basic_string&lt;char32_t,*&gt;">
    <DisplayString Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &lt; _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">{_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf,s32}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &gt;= _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">{_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr,s32}</DisplayString>
    <StringView Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &lt; _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf,s32</StringView>
    <StringView Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &gt;= _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr,s32</StringView>
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="[size]" ExcludeView="simple">_Mypair._Myval2._Mysize</Item>
      <Item Name="[capacity]" ExcludeView="simple">_Mypair._Myval2._Myres</Item>
      <Item Name="[allocator]" ExcludeView="simple">_Mypair</Item>
      <ArrayItems>
        <Size>_Mypair._Myval2._Mysize</Size>
        <ValuePointer Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &lt; _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf</ValuePointer>
        <ValuePointer Condition="_Mypair._Myval2._Myres &gt;= _Mypair._Myval2._BUF_SIZE">_Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr</ValuePointer>
      </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
```

---

**Edit**

See below the final watch console :
(also please note that you should only copy part of the `stl.natvis` that you want, it seems that a full copy/past does not work.)

[image]

Comment: Could you show your debugger window look like after updating the natvis file ?

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, Malick:) Please mark your reply as the answer, so it would help other community members who meet the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

i find that the langauge you select in VS will impact this.
the .natvis xml file's schema is definited in $(VSINSTALLDIR)/xml/schemas/$(LANG)/natvis.xsd,
in my computer there are two version: 1033 and 2052, and the later one is newer than the other, it has much more elements definited(such as <SmartPointerUsage> which is used in the stl.nativs).
if you find your debugger's variable inspection doesn't work, you may try to change the language to an special one which has a newer natvis.xsd.